# JQuery - trigger click event without page reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple form on a page

```
<div class="data-form">
    <p>Are you hungry?</p>
    <form>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="yes">Yes</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="no">No</label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <a id="yes" href="https://someurl.php?ans=yes"></a>
    <a id="no" href="https://someurl.php?ans=no"></a>
</div>
```

When a user selects an option and then clicks submit, I need to remove the form and replace it with Thank you.  To do this, I do the following

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var radioValue = $("input[name='optradio']:checked").val();
    if(radioValue == "yes") {
        $('.data-form').html('');
        $('.data-form').html('<p>Thank you</p>');
    }
    if(radioValue=="no") {
        $('.data-form').html('');
        $('.data-form').html('<p>Thank you</p>');
    }
});
```

This is the part where I am trying to figure out is possible.  In the form, you can see there are two anchor tags, one for yes and one for no.  Now inside my JQuery, if they chose Yes, I could do something like this

```
$('a#yes')[0].click();
```

Now that will reload the page with the url being

```
https://someurl.php?ans=yes
```

It is important that this url triggers, because I am not doing anything with the data they submit (I am not storing it in a database or anything like that).  Instead, I am using the Apache logs.  Within the Apache logs, if I see that the above url has been triggered, I know someone has clicked Yes, and vice-versa.  I have to do it this way due to some external program I am using.

Now this all works, and I can see the responses in my logs.  However, the problem with triggering the click event is that it reloads the page.

What I am wondering, is it possible to somehow trigger this click event without the page reloading?  Whilst still being able to see the response within my Apache logs?

I was thinking about somehow using Ajax to achieve this, but I am not posting my data anywhere so not sure if possible? Any information as to the options I have appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So you simply want to change the URL without actually navigating, correct?

Comment: If you want something to appear in the server logs, then you need to issue some kind of request (GET, PUT, et al).  Maybe you could step back and tell us what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: You could rewrite this whole code in just 2 instructions :  `e.preventDefault(); $('.data-form').empty().html('<p>Thank you</p>');` Would do the same thing, faster and cleaner.

Comment: I am essentially trying to track the amount of yes and no's that have been submitted.  I can only use the logs though, and the page can't reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend using an AJAX call to to submit the form. You will be given additional flexibility and the URL does not have to change. The form will submit to the URL you give it(The one you have above) and the section will change to the desired verbiage. 
An additional change will be to change the type="submit" input to a button. This will not submit the form on click (and no additional work arounds will be needed to stop the submission).

Updated the Fiddle to include both the radio button example and the anchor tags as described. Update the URL to your URL. This is running using JQuery.

HTML:

```
<div class="data-form">
  <p>Are you hungry?</p>
  <form>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="yes">Yes</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="no">No</label>
    <button type="button" class="submitButton1 btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <a id="areYouHungryOption" data-value="yes">Yes</a>
  <a id="areYouHungryOption" data-value="no">No</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".submitButton1").click(function() {

  if ($('input[name="optradio"]:checked').size() > 0) {
    submitData($('input[name="optradio"]:checked').val());
  } else {
    alert('Please select an option!');
  }
})

$("a#areYouHungryOption").click(function() {
  submitData($(this).data("value"));
})

var submitData = function(answer) {
  $.ajax({

      method: "GET",
      url: "/echo/html/",
      data: {
        ans: $('input[name="optradio"]:checked').val()
      }
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
      $('.data-form').html('Thanks for your feedback!');
    });
}
```

See the following JSFiddle project for the example

https://jsfiddle.net/bgerhards/3y0vwf2m/

Comment: You've got errors in your script and OP wants something for when  clicking on the anchor tag, not when submitting the form.

Comment: It doesn't need to be anchor tags, I just need to see the url of the page with the parameter yes or no, within the Apache logs.  In this example, why do you GET google.com?

Comment: I set it as Google.com for example. I just updated the Fiddle and will be adding notes above. Update the URL with your web page minus the variables (so https://someurl.php as you have above).

Comment: Thank you for your input, I shall give it a test as soon as I am back to my computer to see if it gets recorded in the Apache log.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var answer; // Set a variable in the main scope.

$('a#yes')[0].click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Don't go to a new page.
    answer = 'yes'; // Set the answer variable in the main scope.
});
```

Now you can use this value somewhere else in your script.

Comment: Yet, I recommend you to use a different HTML element instead of the anchor element.

Comment: This however would not show up in the Apache log would it?

Comment: You can try looking into AJAX to make a connection with a script that writes to your Apache log.

Comment: This answer does not give any way to actually submit the form. This is not what the requested was looking for.

Comment: @BrianGerhards Yea, that's why I mentioned AJAX in the comment right above yours.